# Using android.view.SurfaceView with a camera on part of the screen

Tags: android, camera

I trying to put together an Android app that will take a picture and process it in some way.  I'd like the layout to be similar to Google Goggles.  Meaning, camera preview on the top, and some controls on the bottom using portrait orientation.

I've built a first version using code sample from [here](http://www.androidph.com/2008/11/camera-capture.html).  This works, but I want to add a button on the bottom.

I've modified my main.xml to look as follows (based on comments from this post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <android.view.SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/snap" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Snap"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I run this code I get the following exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  199): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  199): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beerometer/com.beerometer.ImageCapture}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Android.view.SurfaceView
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class Android.view.SurfaceView
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at com.beerometer.ImageCapture.onCreate(ImageCapture.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(  199): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Android.view.SurfaceView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfc7b0
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime(  199):    ... 20 more
```

When I replace the SurfaceView above with something else, e.g. a TextView, that it displays, but in landscape.

How can I get a camera preview on part of the screen using portrait view?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, your layout probably won't give you what you want. Consider using a `RelativeLayout`, with the `Button` anchored to the bottom, and the `SurfaceView` anchored to the top of the screen and the top of the `Button`.

Also, you have a duplicate `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on your `SurfaceView` that you don't need. The one on your root element will suffice.

In terms of your exception, there may be more detail in your stack trace that you are missing, explaining why `startPreview()` failed. Look for a "Caused by" or other line mid-way through the stack trace. If you can't identify it, edit your question and paste in the entire stack trace (and ping me via a comment on this answer, since I won't know about the edit otherwise).

You might also experiment with [this book example](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/) as another `Camera` preview app, to see if there's something about how I approach the problem that works better for your circumstance.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply.  I fixed my code as you suggested, and now I'm getting a different exception.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I Use SurfaceView in a Widget (I have read that it can't be done, as it is not supported) also can you please have a look on this [Turn on Camera from widget in Nexus S and Galaxy SII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858545/turn-on-camera-from-widget-in-nexus-s-and-galaxy-sii) ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers: "Can I Use SurfaceView in a Widget" -- if by "Widget" you mean "app widget", then, no, you cannot use a `SurfaceView` in an app widget.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not missing something, you cannot just use SurfaceView as is. You need a derived class of your own. I usually create this view programmatically, and give it the full screen. But you can cover parts of it with other views, including buttons:

```
 setContentView(new CameraView());
 View mainscreen = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mainscreen, null, false);
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams generalLayoutParam = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
 addContentView(mainscreen, generalLayoutParam);
```

Comment: It is possible, check the example on top.

Comment: you should be able to. but now I'm having problem where i get this error on nexus 7, but not on another device

Comment: @LassiKinnunen: can you be more specific? Maybe your error deserves a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a surfaceView. From the surfaceView you can get the SurfaceHolder which then can be used to set the camera's previewDisplay.

```
        SurfaceView preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    SurfaceHolder previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

You'll need to implement the SurfaceHolder.Callback method in order to update the preview size properly. In surfaceCreated set the previewDisplay of the camera. On surfaceChanged update the previewSize for the camera.

```
camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
```

In fact [the example mentioned before](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java) is a very good reference!