# How to properly overlay UI Widgets over SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, camera

I've got a portrait camera preview working inside a RelativeLayout, a button and a textview. They are there, but not visible, they react to touch actions properly. How do i setup the Z-Order or priority?
This is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+layout/frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></SurfaceView>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:onClick="hablar" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"></Button>
<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="EditText" android:id="@+id/edita"></EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I am stuck on this issue for last 2 days, have you found solution for this?

Comment: The URLs below offer some good info on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485141/using-android-view-surfaceview-with-a-camera-on-part-of-the-screen http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/

Answer (score 4):

just put a View over SurfaceView:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lalalalala" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The SurfaceView Overlay sample in ApiDemos shows how to do this.  Look for the "SurfaceView Overlay" section here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/index.html

Comment: I've seen that example, but i'm working with a SurfaceView, and it doesn't work. Is there any way to make it that way?

Comment: @hackbod Can I Use SurfaceView in a Widget (I have read that it can't be done, as it is not supported) also can you please have a look on this [Turn on Camera from widget in Nexus S and Galaxy SII](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858545/turn-on-camera-from-widget-in-nexus-s-and-galaxy-sii)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not intuitive at all, but I found how to do it.
Unlike Linear Layouts, order of declaration does NOT define the Z order in Relative Layouts.
I was able of overlaying a textview over the Camera Preview by declaring both views
in XML and, and overlaying them programatically on my Activity's onCreate Method.

Suppose you have an XML with a TextView with a nice transparent backgroud that you want to overlay over the Camera Preview frame layout, because why not?, it looks cool!:

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtnombotiga"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ola ke ase"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"    
        android:background="#55ffffff" 
       />
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="240dp">     
  </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If left like that, the camera will cover your text, no matter what :(
To solve it, let´s go programatical, and:
1) detach the TextView from its parent Layout
2) attach it to the camera´s frame layout *after* attaching the camera first.

Heres the code

OnCreate(){
...blaa blaaa...

```
//Create camera instance and reference to our frame Layout
mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);        
FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
//Add camera to the Frame Layout
preview.addView(mPreview);
//Get reference to the TextView you want to overlay and type something funny
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtnombotiga);     
txt.setText("ola keee aseee!");
//1) Step 1, here comes the magic! dettach the textView from its original Layout
((ViewGroup)txt.getParent()).removeView(txt);
//1) Step 2, voila! attach it to the View, order matters here so it will appear on 
//top of the camera!
preview.addView(txt);
```

This is the general way to do it, If you need more details let me know.
I need to meet deadlines at work, so I use the first solution that comes up to my mind, sometimes not the most elegant or efficient, if you know a better way of doing it, please share it with us!

Comment: The text will be on top of camera if you change the order of TextView and FrameLayout in the RelativeLayout. <RelativeLayout><FrameLayout ><TextView ></RelativeLayout>

And your solution is work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have it working in a FrameLayout where the SurfaceView is sibling to a ZoomControl. That is, this structure works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Maybe the RelativeLayout breaks it?