# How to open camera Activity in selected Area

Tags: android, camera

Every Body, 
I am new in android world.So i need your help.

I Want to know that how we can open camera activity in selected area. In such a manner-

AS in given below screen-shot. It is not compulsory to open in circular area, in my app i can open in any customize area either may be circular , rectangular or in square shape:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485141/using-android-view-surfaceview-with-a-camera-on-part-of-the-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

In this page you can see an example: [SurfaceViewExample](http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/camera-preview-on-surfaceview.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need surface holder and a surface view in your activity. If you need some explanation then check [Android Camera Surface View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482057/android-camera-surface-view/10482872#10482872) link hope it will help you. Any doubt you can ask I will try to explain it.

Comment: A simple layout i am creating in code so you need not to worry about XML. If you want to create layout in XML then simply use VideoView and typecast it in surfaceview (super class of video view) it will work.

Comment: camera = Camera.open(); camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); Both above line show error for me.....// the method open() is undefined for type camera     and same for  setPreviewDisplay(holder)..... So in that case what should i do... please help me....

Comment: which android version you are using

Comment: for android 2.3 and above Camera.Open(camera_index) will be used as it supports multiple camearas(front and back camera) so pass either 0 or 1 as camera index.