# Camera in a frame

Tags: java, android, android-camera

i need to know if there is a possibility to put a camera (with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) in a Activity splitted in two part , in the top the camera , and in a buttom part a listview of the captured images.
I'm sorry if this question is simple or stupid, but i'm new in the Android programming.
Thx Alessandro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950904/how-to-open-camera-activity-in-selected-area

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to launch the external camera app with a intent, using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.
So, no its not possible to style/modify another activity/app.

Comment: Thx for your answer, with the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE start an External App (usually default cam) but this is external. is possible put this app in a frame or so in a frame?

Comment: No, it's not possible to put an external app in a frame unless you create your own flavor of android